# Are some MAPI named properties known and thus always return the same Tag when using GetIDsFromNames with MAPI_CREATE?

Tags: outlook, vsto, mapi

In my c# VSTO Outlook project I am using the [GetNamesFromIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapiprop-getnamesfromids) to get a property name from one message and then adding it to a second message with [GetIDsFromNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapiprop-getidsfromnames) with the `MAPI_CREATE` flag set so that the property is added. I then add the value.

My understanding of GetIDsFromNames is that when it sets a "new" property then a new and unique tag is generated. This is done so that tags do not clash.

1. Is it possible on a newly created message that setting a named property with GetIDsFromNames that MAPI gives it the same Tag number it has had on previous messages?
2. Am I right that GetNamesFromIDs accepts, and GetIDsFromNames returns, only the the upper 2 byte property id and to use what I get from GetIDsFromNames I need to add back the type?

No.2 I cannot seem to read anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that is exactly how it works - once a mapping it created, is stays the same for the lifetime of the parent message store. You can see existing mapping in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click `IMsgStore` button (or `IMAPIFolder` or `IMessage`) and then `GetNamesFromIDs` button.
2. Yes, you always need to set the type. Keep in mind that once a property is used (i.e. used to set a property) with a particular type (unless it is `PT_STRING8` vs `PT_UNICODE`), you will not be able to use that property with a different type.